# warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’ in C

Tags: c, warnings, compiler-warnings, scanf

I have the following code in C:

```
(void)fscanf(fp, "%*d %*d %d %d %d\n",&z, &e, &a);
```

I cast the call to void as the return value of fscanf is irrelevant for me. But I get the following warning when compiling:

```
warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
 (void)fscanf(fp, "%*d %*d %d %d %d\n",&z, &e, &a);
```

Shouldn't the '(void)' have taken that warning out?

Comment: No, because the attribute "warn_unused_result" was placed in the function prototype in the header file. That means that a more experienced programmer is telling you, in no uncertain terms, that the return value from `fscanf` is never irrelevant.

Comment: I love *NEVER IRRELEVANT*.

Comment: I'm sure you realize that you have more specifiers than variables.

Comment: @bruceg No, there are only 3 specifiers that store values. The other 2 `%*d` parse the respective values, but suppress assignment due to the `*` modifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a nice warning, since ignoring the return value of `fscanf()` could lead to undefined behavior. I suppose you can't silence that warning unless you handle the return value, that's very easy

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%*d%*d%d%d%d", &z, &e, &a) == 3)
    usevalues(z, e, a);
else
    reportproblem_do_not_use_z_e_or_a();
```

Warnings are good teachers of how to correctly use functions, you should never ignore `fscanf()`'s return value, and more importantly you should never ignore/silence a warning. If the compiler is warning about something, it must be because you are doing something wrong<sup>1</sup>.

In this case, if you don't check the value and proceed to use `z`, `e` or `a` their content might be undefined at the moment of reading them and some unexpected things will occur.

The worst part is that it will be very difficult to find out that, these unexpected things (*calculations for example*) are happening because you *DID NOT CHECK* `fscanf()`'s return value.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Except in very few situations, where you intentionally do something that will trigger a warning. But those kinds of situations only happen when you are a very experienced [c](/questions/tagged/c) programmer.</sub>

Comment: How does ignoring a return value lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: Because `z`, `e`, and `a` might be not initialized by `fscanf()`, so reading from them would be undefined behavior because their contents are undefined.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with ignoring the return value.

Comment: It sure has, because if you ignore the return value **OF `fscanf()`** (not any function, but ignoring the return value of any function is bad anyway) then you would not know for sure whether or not `z`, `e`, or `a` were initialized, unless you explicitly initialized them before calling `fscanf()`.

Comment: The return value tells you how many items successfully matched and assigned. There is a possible error condition, but no undefined behavior.

Comment: If you proceed to read from the values that have not been *assigned*, my answer clearly states that. If you think that my answer is misleading please feel free to downvote.

Comment: I understand, thank you for pointing that out. It might help future readers to clarify.

Comment: You are assuming that `z`, `e`, and `a` were not initialized *prior* to calling fscanf -- if they were previously initialized then the behavior is well defined -- fscanf will NOT overwrite them with random data if the pattern does not match, and is guarenteed to leave the unmatched args unchanged.  This is actually a pretty common technique when scanf is used with a `%n` option.

Comment: @ChrisDodd If you know `%n` you already know enough not to use the `scanf()`s wrong. Please note that I said: Could lead to ...

Answer (score 4):

This is the defined behavior for this attribute. When a function is marked with this attribute, the return value cannot be ignored by casting it to void.

See this [bug report 25009](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25509) for an interesting discussion.

Comment: Excelent link, the discussion is really nice too.

Comment: Ergo, just use `-Wno-unused-result` that's the advice from the GCC guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the warning by using a noop if:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%*d %*d %d %d %d\n",&z, &e, &a));
```

Comment: Doesn't this trigger a warning that the `if` is followed by a semicolon? I don't like this code, it is difficult to understand and might easily lead to misinterpretations. You answered the question, no doubt. Still I don't like the answer. Getting rid of warnings must not lower your code quality!